# create the vpc flow log from terraform in existing environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-vpc, terraform-provider-aws

I am new to terraform and still learing. 
I know there is way you can import your existing infrastructure to terraform and have the state file created. But As if now I have multiple AWS accounts and multiple regions in those accounts which have multiple VPCs.
My task is to create vpc flow log through terraform. 
Is it possible? 
If it is, could you please help me or direct me how to get this thing done.

Comment: If you are asking how to use the aws provider across accounts, in the `provider "aws"` block put `profile = var.aws_profile` and set aws_profile to whatever the alias is for the credentials you have in ~/.aws/credentials. See the docs for more info https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/index.html

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, albeit a little messy. You will need to create a provider block (with a unique alias) for each account/region combination you have (you can use profiles but I think roles is best), and select those providers in your resources appropriately.

```
provider "aws" {
  alias  = "acct1uswest2"
  region = "us-west-2"
  assume_role {
    role_arn     = "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:role/ROLE_NAME"
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  alias  = "acct2useast1"
  region = "us-east-1"
  assume_role {
    role_arn     = "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:role/ROLE_NAME"
  }
}

resource "aws_flow_log" "flow1" {
  provider = aws.acct1uswest2
  vpc_id = "vpc id in account 1" # you mentioned the vpc already exists, so you can either import the vpc and reference it's .id attribute here, or just put the id here as a string
...
}

resource "aws_flow_log" "flow2" {
  provider = aws.acct2useast1
  vpc_id = "vpc id in account 2"
...
}
```

Suggest you read up on importing resources (and the implications) [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/usage.html)
More on multiple providers [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/providers.html#alias-multiple-provider-instances)

Comment: correct me if i am wrong, I need to do this for every single VPC in each region in each account.